# Detect iPhone Xr and iPhone Xs in JavaScript

Tags: iphone, resolution, fingerprint

I have a fingerprint javascript to detect the screensize, the OS and the chip inside an iPhone.

For instance:
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_4 like Mac OS X)
available_resolution = 667,375
Apple Inc.~Apple A11 GPU

The problem though is that iPhone Xs Max and iPhone Xr have the same resolution as I see it, the same OS og same Apple chip. So how can I see the difference between iPhone Xs Max and iPhone Xr.

Comment: I'd like to know this as well.

Answer (score 0):

try window.devicePixelRatio - i tested the two devices on browserstack and the XS Max returned 3 and the XR returned 2

in my app i'm using it like this

```
if (window.devicePixelRatio === 3 && screen.height === 896) {
  // is iphone XS Max
}
```